# How to avoid closing of Gtk.Dialog in Python?

Tags: python, dialog, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I have a form in a Gtk.Dialog which has an "Ok" button and a "Cancel" button.

When I click on the Ok button, the dialog returns 1 and when I click on Cancel button, it returns 0.

What I want to make is to validate the fields of the form so that if any field has invalid data, like letters in a numeric field or empty fields, the dialog can not be destroyed if Ok button is pressed.

Comment: Show us some code, so that we can answer more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom dialog. [Here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html#custom-dialogs) you can find an example. Make shure to destroy the dialog only if your validation succeded.

Comment: It worked, when I click on Ok button and the form isn't filled correctly, the dialog doesn't destroy until the fields are filled correctly. Thank you.