# Avoiding Closing a GTK Dialog

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, gtk, gtk3

Is there any way to run code after the OK button is pressed but before the dialog is closed in a GTK dialog? I want to be able to syntax check some code entered into the dialog after the OK button is pressed, with the option to keep the dialog open if the code doesn't compile. After a bit of googling I was able to find [How to avoid closing of Gtk.Dialog in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089128/how-to-avoid-closing-of-gtk-dialog-in-python), but the answer was regrettably short of details, so I couldn't figure out how to implement this. How does one go about doing this?

**EDIT**: Although the linked question asks about Python specifically, I don't actually care about any particular language. I'm using the Haskell bindings, but I'm fine with answers in any language with GTK+ bindings.

**EDIT**: If you find this question trying to figure out how to do validation, but don't have the complex requirements I have, I highly recommend looking at [@AlexanderDmitriev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553792/7345298) below.

Comment: Have you followed the link in the answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, I already know how to construct a custom dialog - it's custom dialogs with content needing to be validated before the dialog is closed which I don't know how to make.

Answer (score 2):

I'm adding another answer in order to leave previous answer valid.

I see 2 ways to achieve desired behaviour.

1. Use deprecated `gtk_dialog_get_action_area` and pack a button there
2. Stop signal emission to prevent GtkDialog from "seeing" that the response button was pressed.

Both ways can be found in code below. Find `deprecated` for 1st approach and `awesome` for 2nd

```
    import gi
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import Gtk

    class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):

        button_state = True

        def awesome_cb (button, de):
            if de.button_state:
                print("Awesome ok")

            else:
                print("Awesome  Not allowed")
                button.stop_emission_by_name ("clicked")

        def deprecated_cb (button, de):
            if de.button_state:
                print("Deprecated ok")
                de.response(11)
            else:
                print("Deprecated Not allowed");

        def switch_state(button, de):
            de.button_state = not de.button_state
            de.dialog_ok_btn.set_sensitive (de.button_state)


        def __init__(self, parent):
            Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
                (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                 Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

            self.set_default_size(150, 100)

            label = Gtk.Label("This is a dialog to display additional information")

            box = self.get_content_area()
            state_switcher_btn = Gtk.Button ("Switch")
            state_switcher_btn.connect ("clicked", DialogExample.switch_state, self)

            box.add(label)
            box.add(state_switcher_btn)

            hard_work_button = Gtk.Button ("deprec")
            hard_work_button.connect ("clicked", DialogExample.deprecated_cb, self)

            carea = self.get_action_area()
            carea.add (hard_work_button)

            tfb = Gtk.Button ("awesome");
            tfb.connect("clicked", DialogExample.awesome_cb, self)
            self.add_action_widget(tfb, 12)

            self.dialog_ok_btn = self.get_widget_for_response (Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
            self.show_all()

        def do_response (self, response_id):
            print ("Response! ID is ", response_id)

    class DialogWindow(Gtk.Window):

        def __init__(self):
            Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Dialog Example")

            self.set_border_width(6)

            button = Gtk.Button("Open dialog")
            button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

            self.add(button)

        def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
            dialog = DialogExample(self)
            response = dialog.run()

            if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
                print("The OK button was clicked")
            elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
                print("The Cancel button was clicked")

            dialog.destroy()

    win = DialogWindow()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like GtkDialog itself doesn't allow to cancel button press (which is OK from user's point of view). However, every time user changes something, you can check it and make buttons sensitive or not. I've extended [code from answer to mentioned question](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dialogs.html#custom-dialogs)

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):

    #this variable controls, whether OK is sensitive
    button_state = True 

    def switch_state(button, de):
        print ("switcher")
        de.button_state = not de.button_state
        de.set_response_sensitive (Gtk.ResponseType.OK, de.button_state)


    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.set_default_size(150, 100)

        label = Gtk.Label("This is a dialog to display additional information")

        box = self.get_content_area()
        # a button to switch OK's sensitivity
        state_switcher_btn = Gtk.Button ("Switch")
        state_switcher_btn.connect ("clicked", DialogExample.switch_state, self)

        box.add(label)
        box.add(state_switcher_btn)

        self.show_all()

    def do_response (self, response_id):
        print ("Override! ID is ", response_id)

class DialogWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Dialog Example")

        self.set_border_width(6)

        button = Gtk.Button("Open dialog")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        self.add(button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = DialogExample(self)
        response = dialog.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("The OK button was clicked")
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("The Cancel button was clicked")

        dialog.destroy()

win = DialogWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Clever solution! Unfortunately the particular type of validation which I would like to do - syntax checking - produces a long, detailed error message which I would like to display in a message dialog, but otherwise I would use this solution. I'm editing my question to reflect this.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem. In my `switch_state` function you can still `get_content_area` and pack an error message there. Or even pack a label in `GtkRevealer` and show and hide text when user's input is right or wrong, respectively

Comment: Good point - I didn't think of that. However, I have been thinking about your solution and realised that unfortunately it wouldn't work anyway. Your answer requires some place to put code to swap the sensitivity of the button. In your code, you put this code in the `switch_state` method. My problem is related to a TextView, so in order to do this properly I would need to check the entered code every time the text is changed. However, this means that I would need to re-parse the entered code every time the user enters another character, ...

Comment: ... taking a long time and making the application less than ideal to use. I have edited my question to better reflect my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Alexander Dmitriev's hint to use `button.stop_emission_by_name`, I came up with this solution which is probably what you were asking for:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyDialog(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.add_buttons(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                         Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        self.connect("response", self._cb_response)

    def _cb_response(self, widget, response_id):
        if response_id == Gtk.ResponseType.OK and self._check_invalid():
            msg = Gtk.MessageDialog(
                parent=self,
                text="There are errors in what you entered.\n\n"
                "Are you sure you want to continue?",
                message_type=Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION,
                buttons=Gtk.ButtonsType.YES_NO,
            )
            response = msg.run()
            msg.destroy()
            if response == Gtk.ResponseType.NO:
                widget.stop_emission_by_name("response")
                return True
        return False

    def _check_invalid(self):
        """Placeholder for checking for problems"""
        return True

dialog = MyDialog()
dialog.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had this as well. I decided to catch the `response` signal. I had a function that would handle the validation. However, the function that handles the `response` signal always returns `True` to show GTK that the signal has already been handled and the dialog doesn't close. If the dialog needed closing, I did so manually.

```
myDialogWindow.connect("response", validate_response)

def validate_response(dialog, response_id):
     # validate
     if correct:
        dialog.destroy()
     else:
        print("Something went wrong")
     return True
```

Though this gets the job done, I'm not certain this the most GTK'ish solution.